# Удаление View

Tags: массивы, java, view

Добрый день. Данный метод реализует создание массива ImageView, берет анимации из класса и проигрывает их. Как можно удалить ненужные ImageView после использования? Сейчас они просто остаются в начальных позициях.

```
public void ExplosiveInCurPos(int x, int y)
{
    MassAnimDead = null;
    MassAnimDead = new ImageView[r.nextInt(20)+2];
    deadAnim = null;
    deadAnim = new Animdead(MassAnimDead.length);
    for (int i = 0; i<MassAnimDead.length; i++)
    {
        MassAnimDead[i] = RandLoadImage(1);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams Anim = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(sizeReturn(1)/50,sizeReturn(1)/50);
        MassAnimDead[i].setAnimation(deadAnim.getAnim(i));
        Anim.leftMargin = x;
        Anim.topMargin = y;
        if ((i==1)||(i==2))
        {
        Anim.leftMargin += sizeReturn(1)/16;
        Anim.topMargin += sizeReturn(1)/16;
        }
        MassAnimDead[i].setLayoutParams(Anim);
        StarScreen.addView(MassAnimDead[i]);
    }
    new CountDownTimer(500,500) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long arg0) 
        {
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            for (int i=0; i<MassAnimDead.length; i++)
            {
                StarScreen.removeViewAt(MassAnimDead[i].getId());
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Любой View можно удалить при помощи такого кода.

```
View v;
...
((ViewGroup)v.getParent()).removeView(v);
```

То есть в вашем случае удалять их нужно так:

```
for (int i=0; i<MassAnimDead.length; i++)
{
    ((ViewGroup)MassAnimDead[i].getParent()).removeView(MassAnimDead[i]);
}
```

Еще пара замечаний к коду:  
 имена переменных должны начинаться со строчных(маленьких) букв  
 названия функций должны начинаться со строчных(маленьких) букв
 по моему, данный код является дичайшим велосипедом, изобретенным для покадровой анимации при помощи ImageView(я очень даже могу ошибаться). Если это так, то опишите, чего вы хотите достич этим кодом, и вам помогут найти правильное решение...

Comment: Спасибо за замечания, впредь буду их придерживаться.
Данная штука делает некоторое подобие взрыва. massAnimDead отображает случайное количество осколков, которые разлетаются в случайных направлениях.

Comment: объектом какого класса является у вас `StarScreen`? Я посчитал, что наследником `ViewGroup`

Comment: А вот еще [ссылка][1] на документацию о том, как правильно сделать анимацию...
    


  [1]: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html

Comment: StarScreen это FrameLayout, на котором все рисуется. Хорошо, но чем плох этот подход? Анимация генерируется отдельно в классе и передается на отрисовку. Этот код не создает анимацию он просто её отображает.

Comment: Если это FrameLayout, то тогда можно использовать такой код:    

    StarScreen.removeView(MassAnimDead[i]);

Comment: Спасибо за ценные советы, буду разбираться.

Comment: Однако не все так просто, если вызывать StarScreen.removeView(MassAnimDead[i]); сразу после создания все успешно удаляется. Но если через секунду, то все остается где было.

Comment: значит в массиве находятся не те View, которые лежат на StarScreen